# property to retrieve and set Text node value: data or nodeValue?

Tags: javascript, html

Which one should I use?

http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/CharacterData/data

http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/nodeValue

That site recommends using nodeValue yet shows data as having far better compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use nodeValue, because data specifies it is the same as nodeValue.

The page clarifies:

> The nodeValue property is the best way of manipulating the value of
>   nodes - preferable over more specialized properties, such as data or
>   value, because of various browser issues.

Here is a good answer from another discussion on the topic:

> The nodeValue field is defined for all Nodes and maps to different
>   things depending on the node type. The data field is defined on Nodes
>   that inherit from CharacterData, which is to say Text, CDATASection,
>   and Comment nodes. For those three node types, nodeValue maps straight
>   to data. I know it's weird, but the DOM does have quite a few such
>   irrelevant duplication due to trying to make the vendors happy back
>   then.

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/53314

Comment: Yes i mentioned that I noticed this message. Why, then, is compatibility for `nodeValue` less complete than for `data`?

Comment: @StevenLu The disclaimer of `data` being more compatible is that it always works correctly *when available*. `nodeValue` is supported in Safari except in comments, Opera had bugs, and Internet Explorer 5.5 couldn't retrieve attribute nodes.